# Upgrade HCL ME V1 tablet to make it usable again

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-services, operating-system

I have **HCL ME V1** tablet :

1. preinstalled with Android 4.0.4 (Ice-cream Sandwich) OS.
2. It has 4GB of internal SD memory
3. 1GB DDR3 RAM and
4. 1 GHz, Cortex A8 processor

It used to work fine when I had bought it, but with time, the device is becoming quite unusable in the sense that the android os is quite old and there was no update from the manufacturer.

Moreover it has no playstore. Which was not a problem previously as I could manually download the apks from third party sites and just install them on the device, it used to work fine. But recently I see all the newer apks show "there was a problem while parsing" and technically it is becoming unusable. All the older browsers in it show incompatibility errors when I try to load a web page.

Moreover, I cannot install any apps from Google like Chrome, Youtube etc.

So could you suggest me a step by step detailed guide as to how I can revive the device, with some newer android os (installing manually) or some other lightweight os which could be installed on that device or someway as to how I could install Google Play on it.

I too have a smart phone with a similar hardware configuration, which supports Android 9 without much issues. Please could anyone help me, with a detailed step by step guide.

Comment: you can't upgrade to higher android version unless somebody has built custom ROM. source code is required (sometimes proprietary binary blobs) which is hardware specific so it depends on vendor (usually they are forced to provide but may violate their own license agreement). in any case ROM development is off-topic here. search for ready-to-flash custom ROM and ask here in case you don't understand the flashing instructions. if you can't find ROM use older apps. also check [microG](https://github.com/microg/GmsCore/wiki) or [OpenGApps](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: ok I shall try it @alecxs